# JavaScript Validation Not Alerting User

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am using javascript to validate a web form for submission to a database, I have coded the form and the validation, but it does not seem to work.

When the form is completed and it is valid it is meant to go to a success page in a separate HTML file, but if it is not valid, the text on the form turns red, a message box pops up and alerts the user that it is invalid. On Chrome and IE, it seems to display the error but go to the success page anyway. The Message Box does not come up either, i only see the text turning red before it goes to the success page.

I wanted to know how to fix this. I have searched on the Internet but found no solution.

I have a function called `validateForm()`, which is a series of if statements checking the if the fields are valid, and if they are not, a variable called 'result' is set to false, at the end, it sends the alert message and returns the variable 'result'.

The code for my submit button is here:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm();" />
```

The Success Page is set in the form code as an 'action'.

Here is my Validate Form :

```
function validateForm(){
    var result = true;
    var msg = "";

    if(document.ExamEntry.name.value==""){
        msg+="You must enter your Name \n";
        document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
        document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
        result = false;
    }

    if(document.ExamEntry.subject.value==""){
        msg+="You must enter the Subject \n";
        document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
        document.getElementById('subject').style.color="red";
        result = false;
    }

    if(document.ExamEntry.examNumber.value=="")
    {
        msg+="You must enter the Examination Number \n";
        document.ExamEntry.examNumber.focus;
        document.getElementById('examnumber').style.color="red";
        result = false;
    }

    if(document.ExamEntry.examNumber.value.length!=4)
    {
        msg+="Your Examination Number must be 4 characters long \n";
        document.ExamEntry.examNumber.focus;
        document.getElementById('examnumber').style.color="red";
        result = false;
    }

    var lvlmsg="";
    for(var i=0; i < document.ExamEntry.level.length; i++)
        {
            if(document.ExamEntry.level[i].checked)
            {
                lvlmsg = document.ExamEntry.level[i].value;
                break;
            }
        }
    if(lvlmsg=="")
        {
            msg+="You Must Indicate Your Level";
            result=false;
            document.getElementById('radioButtons').style.color="red";
        }
    else
        {
            alert(lvlmsg);
        }

    if(msg==""){
        return result;
    }
    else{
        alert(msg);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code for validateForm?

Comment: validateForm() function must return false if validation fails

Comment: U have to add your validateForm() to make your question complete

Comment: I'd suggest attaching this to the form submit event rather than the click event on the button - apart from anything else this won't prevent the form submitting if the user presses the enter key (don't forget you should still be performing server validation regardless).

Answer (score 0):

I created a form without the radio buttons and changed the function call.

I think the mistake is here:

```
<form name="ExamEntry" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
    <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" />
    <input type="text" id="examnumber" name="examNumber" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onlick="return validateForm()" />
</form>
```

I changed the function call to `onsubmit` (because I think it's better practice) and `return validateForm()` to simply `validateForm()`. Why would you want the `return` statement? Doesn't make sense to me.

http://jsfiddle.net/rcsole/cqy7q/

Comment: I used that because i was supplied a template that i had to adapt, it was working but they wanted some more fields. It still doesn't work though

Comment: BTW to avoid changing the page you could use preventDefault(). As in check if it's valid, if it is window.location otherwise pass